# Delete selected sites cookies on Firefox automatically

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

I set the cookie preferences on each site via Super Agent or manually, however I want to always remove the ones that now force us to accept some pages if we don't pay. So what I want is to delete the cookies of the sites I have listed, as Chrome and Brave do. The only thing I have found is an extension called 'Cookie AutoDelete', but if anyone knows a trick by going into about:config or some other option I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hello, I don't know what kind of `about:config` "trick" you imagine. Random list-like setting that would delete cookies you name? What's wrong with that extension? Edit your post if you want to add something, don't use answers for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want cookies to be saved, you may in Firefox
access these websites in a Private session.

Cookies get deleted at the end of the Private session, as well as
all other data stored during the session.